# Problem with \acs from acronym package: No link in list of acronyms

Tags: links, acronyms

It appears that when using the `acronym` package, a link including the page number is only created in the list of acronyms
when using `\acf`, but not with `\acs` nor `\acl`.
This is a problem in the following case where I'd like to introduce an acronym like this:

```
\acs{TMS}, which was originally introduced as abbreviation for \acl{TMS}, can be used to ...
```

Is there a way to make `\acs` or `\acl` produce a link to this line in the list of acronyms?

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}

\acs{TMS}, which was originally introduced as abbreviation for \acl{TMS}, can be used to ...

The \acf{AWL} works.

\section{Somewhere else...}

\begin{acronym}[abc]
  \acro{TMS}{This Means Nothing} % has no page number in list of acronyms :(
  \acro{AWL}{Acronym With Link}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this has bad effects, but it seems that

```
\acs{TMS}\label{acro:TMS}
```

does what you want, as it will mark the place as if it were the first occurrence of the acronym. Use with care.

The trick consist in writing the correct label in the `.aux` file; the package, in order to ensure uniqueness, adds the prefix `acro:` to the short name of the acronym (or, better, to the argument to its macros). In order to mark the acronym as "used", `\acsu` can be used instead of `\acs`.

Comment: Simple and effective solution. Should be used with `\acsu` (instead of `\acs`), because then the acronym is marked and used and the label is not set a second time.