# Latex acronym package, \acsu does not print the page in list of acronyms

Tags: acronyms

I encounter the following problem when working with the "used" option (`\acsu`) of the acronym package. Here is my minimal working example:

```
 \documentclass[fontsize=11pt, listof=numbered, twoside, open=right, headsepline, plainheadsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\ac{LED}

\acsu{LCD}

\appendix
\chapter{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[ABCD]
    \acro{LED}{Light Emitting Diode}
    \acro{LCD}{Liquid Crystal Display}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

In the list of acronyms, "LED" is printed with the corresponding page, but "LCD" is printed without the page number, although I marked it as used with the `\acsu` command.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me…

Answer (score 3):

This answer is probably too late for you, however, I also had the same problem and solved it.

I found the solution here: [Problem with \acs from acronym package: No link in list of acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39088/problem-with-acs-from-acronym-package-no-link-in-list-of-acronyms)

Seems like `\acsu` only marks it as used such that it will be displayed in short when you type `\ac` later on.

However, it does not insert a label. You should do that manually.

In your case:
`\acsu{LCD}\label{acro:LCD}` should do the trick.

Comment: It may be better to use the internal command `\AC@placelabel` instead of `\label` since this is what normally happens with `\ac`. The internal command contains logic to avoid duplicating the label. In my preamble I have `\makeatletter \newcommand{\aksu}[1]{\AC@placelabel{#1}\acs{#1}} \makeatother`.